# wasRecentlyCreated and wasChanged are not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, model

I am trying to use wasChanged and wasRecentlyCreated of models in laravel project but both of them are false in the below code

```
$saved=$project->accessInfo()->updateOrCreate(['type'=>$request->type],['value'=>$data]);
dd($project->accessInfo[0]->wasChanged(),$project->accessInfo[0]->wasRecentlyCreated,$project->wasRecentlyCreated,$project->wasChanged());

//here is my relation in Project model 
public function accessInfo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Modules\Project\Models\ProjectAccessInfo', 'project_id');
    }
```

also below code returns error

```
dd($project->accessInfo->wasChanged(),$project->accessInfo()->wasRecentlyCreated)
//No such method or attribute  in both cases 
//Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasMany::wasChanged()
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`getChanges` - Get the attributes that were changed.

`getDirty` - Get the attributes that have been changed since last sync.

When you want to know if the model has been edited since it was queried from the database, or isn't saved at all, then you use the `->isDirty()` function.